# Is it possible to download my app preview images from iTunesConnect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I created an app, that supports all the resolutions of apple devices. As a result, I have app preview images in the following resolutions:

- iphone 6 plus
- iphone 6
- iphone 5
- iphone 4 and below aspect ratio
- ipad

The problem is, I deleted the images from my hard drive, and need the exact same images as I am adding app store descriptions in new languages. It would be very tedious to create the images again. Is there a way I can download the images I uploaded in their original resolution ?

EDIT: If I log into itunesconnect and try to right click on the images and copy / download, the images downloaded are of much lower resolution. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score -2):

You can copy/download an app preview image with the same resolution as you added it.  Click on the image in iTunesConnect and then you will see your image with original resolution in full screen mode.